# How to wrap selected text with a div in ipad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection

Its a followup question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433888/is-there-a-way-to-save-the-selected-text-and-highlight-it-again-once-the-page-is). I'm trying to wrap the selected text in a div using [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) but its not working in iPad because window.getSelection().rangeCount is 0.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/jE4w5/

Is there any workaround for this to work in iPad?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986216/get-selected-text-on-ipad-2-with-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475676/cant-get-positioncontainer-infomation-by-click-the-ipad

Comment: Thanks @bažmegakapa. But vclick event only lets me grab the selected text. How can I wrap the selected text in `<div>` in iPad?

Comment: @bažmegakapa: could not able to use Jquery Mobile and backbone together. It throws routing related error.

Comment: I don't have much experience in the areas you mention (selection in iPad, jQuery Mobile), but asking a separate question is always the best choice, even if you haven't received answers to this current question of yours.

Comment: Thanks @bažmegakapa for all  your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) for text selection and highlighting. jQuery Mobile along with backbone.js breaks the page so I used [jQuery FastClick](https://github.com/dave1010/jquery-fast-click) plugin