# Rangy Error: deserializeRange: checksums of serialized range root node do not match after page load

Tags: javascript, rangy, tiki-wiki

I am saving the selection through rangy on my dynamic web page. But when I reload the page and restore the selections, I get the following error:

> Error: deserializeRange: checksums of serialized range root node
>   (f3909155) and target root node (c21b08a9) do not match

The page source is not changed at all and all HTML is same. I am using Tikiwiki CMS.
Any ideas about this?

Comment: It's likely the DOM must be different in some way. Is the DOM altered by scripts that run when the page loads, for example? And are you using the same browser? If you have an example page then I'll take a look.

Comment: @TimDown I dont have the live example right now. But I am using the same browser without any modification in the page source (I compared the page sources and those are same). I dont know how to handle this :(

Comment: using the same lib , facing the exact same issue , were you able to find a fix for this one ? @ArvindBhardwaj

Comment: possible duplicate of [Range.deserializeSelection checksum error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586115/range-deserializeselection-checksum-error)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine , that SO question deals with iFrame , in my case i dont have an iFrame

Comment: @user1537158 see my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this error, you need to pass the `omitChecksum` parameter to the `serializeSelection` function. This will prevent the DOM validation. `serializeSelection` will return the serialized form of the selection which you can save in DB or cookie.

See the following example:

```
var selObj = rangy.getSelection();
var sel = rangy.serializeSelection(selObj, true);
```

Comment: The checksums failing to match means that something is different in the DOM and therefore deserialization has a good chance of failing. I'd be interested in seeing a demo page.

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj , TimDown , can you help me with my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416524/restore-multiple-selections-from-db-using-rangy , im facing the exact same issue , i have created JS fiddle too for demonstration

Comment: @TimDown could you help me with my SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416524/restore-multiple-selections-from-db-using-rangy , i have created a js-fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/janinishant10/wH9Ec/6/

Comment: @user1537158: It's on my list.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the DOM is different in some way. Be sure that before serializing you didn't modify the selection, for example using the rangy *CssClassApplier*.