# Restore multiple selections from db using Rangy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rangy

**What i want to do :**

->Show a plain HTML page to a user
->User has the ability to highlight **text** on that page
->When user logs in next time , i should be able to retrieve and show his previous (multiple) highlight on the page.

**What i have done :**

I used the [Library/API : Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/).With this iam able to select the text and highlight it with the users preferred color.

**The Problem :**

I tried the serialize and de-serialize function , but when i try to deserialize (after page has been reloaded) it gives me an error saying

> checksums of serialized range root node (ec0c8cf0) and target root
>   node (d4997863) do not match

Everytime i reload the page , there is a new root node , how can i fix the deserialize in this case ?

**Created a JS-Fiddle** : [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/janinishant10/wH9Ec/6/embedded/result/) / [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janinishant10/wH9Ec/6/)

What is this - If you check my demo , i select the first word of the description ie "Please " , i get the text highlighted , and i also get the serial as :

> 0/3/1/3/0/1/1/2:9,0/3/1/3/0/1/1/2:9{b3002d92}

so what i did is , i hard coded this serial and put it into the deserializeSelection funciton in the page onLoad function like this :-

```
rangy.deserializeSelection('0/3/1/3/0/1/1/2:9,0/3/1/3/0/1/1/2:9{b3002d92}');
```

so technically , it should highlight the "Please" in the description , whenever the page loads , irrespectively.But it does not , instead give me the above error in block.
Can you help me solve this.please.Thank you

**Extra:**

1.I really do not understand the serialize and de-serialize methods of rangy.

2.My very abstract road map from here is to , do an AJAX call , on page load and fetch all (serialized) selection of the user for this page from my db and iterate over them and do a de-serialize.

Any help , would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: why ajax and not storeage methods used by plugin? Could also modify to use `localStorage` instead of cookie for modern browsers that support it

Comment: also this demo http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/serializer.html  shows how to update input value with serialization, and update dom from an input value. WOuld be same values/methods used if you send to db

Comment: @charlietfl , thank you for the quick response , yes i saw the serialize method , but the difficulty iam facing is , when i de-serialize (to render the highlight) we can do it for only 1 selection , how can i do the same for multiple selections ?

Comment: works fine if you hold `ctrl` to do multiple selections, otherwise you would need to store various selections in an array and send array, then in ajax loop over array to restore

Comment: @charlietfl , im sorry , cant get what your saying , should i press ctrl , do various selection -> do a serialize -> do a de-serialize to get all the selection (this dint work for me :()

Comment: works for me holding `ctrl` to create multiple selections...then serilize them. If need user to be able to make various selections and store at different times would need to serialize each and push to an array which would be sent to server

Comment: @charlietfl , ya actually in chrome i could not do the multiple selection using CTRL , works just fine in FF :)

Comment: @charlietfl , i was able to save the serialized selection to db , but when i reload the page -> i get all the serialized selection -> when i try to deserialize it , it gives me `checksums of serialized range root node do not match after page load` , please can you help deserialize

Comment: suggest creating a demo in jsfiddle.net. Should be able to hot link the plugin script, and can use fiddle ajax url's to mimic page load. WHat do you mean have a new root node every time load page?

Comment: @charlietfl ,added a JS-fiddle to my description, basically i remove the ajax for now, the small aim right now is , to select the first word on load of the page,i have added the description what iam talk about here , can you help

Answer (score 0):

What I think is you should try this:

```
var selObj = rangy.getSelection();
var se = rangy.serializeSelection(selObj, true); //true to avoid DOM checksum
```

Comment: will try that and get back @arvindBharadwaj

Comment: @arvindBharadwaj cant seem to get through , can you help ?