# grab selected text from multiple iframe using rangy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, rangy

This is a [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537032/how-to-grab-selected-text-from-iframe-using-rangy). I've been trying to grab the selected text from multiple iframe using rangy. The code seems to be working for  1st iframe .

i want to grab elements using the same button., for div it works k. but in iframe we need to specify the iframe and when i tried the array of iframes ., that is not working

Comment: Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/suneeshtr/2d6Bk/27/

Comment: not like this. http://jsfiddle.net/suneeshtr/2d6Bk/28/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$(function () {
    $('button').click(function () {
        $.each(iframe, function(idx, vl) {
            var selection = rangy.getSelection(iframe[idx]);
            alert(selection);
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cWV3G/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: just tested here and it worked flawlessly on Chrome and Firefox... Then I got to IE and BAM: got blank alerts... It seems that IE doesn't let you select text on both iframes, but I believe that this is a issue related on how jsfiddle renders the code (the two iframes are inside another iframe generated by jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/2d6Bk/31/)

Try getting the the Rangy iframe selection object and access the `FocusNode` property and get the selected text from that iframe like this:

### JS:

```
$(function () {
 $('button').click(function () {
   iframe.each(function(i){
    if(rangy.getSelection(iframe[i]).focusNode!=null)
     {
        var selection = rangy.getSelection(iframe[i]).focusNode.data;
        alert("Iframe - "+(i+1)+ " selected text : '" +selection+"'");
      }
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: thanks @Aditya your answer is ok., but other one is more easy to use. :)

Comment: The other one pops up an empty alert? Mine is not a complex solution... just checks for `null` values, because it will result in error! :)

Comment: And you can go ahead and just `alert(selection)` , i just wanted to make the solution clearer to you :)

Comment: Since your solution uses "focusNode.data", it's not returning the selected text, but the whole text inside iframe. You should remove it to get only the selected text.